# Segfault in map

Tags: c++, dictionary, insert, std, segmentation-fault

I can't understand why does this code fail with segfault:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    map <string, string> temp;
    map <string, string>::iterator it;
```

S
        string text = "";
        string thatChange = "";
        string whatChange = "";

```
    getline (cin, text);


    while (true)
    {
        getline (cin, thatChange);
        if (thatChange == "-1")
            break;

        getline (cin, whatChange);
        temp.insert(pair <string, string> (thatChange, whatChange));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++)
    {
        string thatChange = it->first ; // thatChange
        string whatChange = it->second; // whatChange
        it++;

        int index = text.find(thatChange);
        text.erase(index, thatChange.size());
        text.insert(index, whatChange);
    }

    cout << "text\n"<< text;

    return 0;
}
```

---

UPD:
Debugger says:

```
No source available for "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string() at 0x7ffff7b75928"
```

Comment: What headers or compiler do you use? I inserted <map> and <iostream> along with `using namespace std;` and compiled with gcc, no segfaults here.

Comment: Please post a full code example that compiles, not just a snipped.

Comment: well, it doesn't crash for me. What compiler are you using and what flags do you pass into it ?

Comment: It doesn't crash for me (on VS2010). Note that you do not change the value of `whatChange` ever. `whatChange` is always the empty string. Post the real code.

Comment: @dirkgently: it is changed after the `break;`

Comment: @progo @rasjani @dirkgently I've got full version of code. Look, please, at updated one.

Comment: @progo seg faults are runtime errors, not compile-time.

Comment: @SilverSun: of course I compiled & tested. :) It's just that the original post had little code and it worked perfectly within the standard and rules.

Comment: @progo Oh I misread it sorry. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string thatChange = it->first ;
```

This line invokes UB. The `it` has never been initialized so far. You ought to initialize this as follows:

```
it = tmp.begin();
```

and to iterate over all the elements of the map use:

```
for (map<string, string>::const_iterator f = temp.begin(), e = temp.end;
     f != e;
     ++f) {
   // ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW the code snippet compiles and runs fine with VS2010 so if you got an error the problem is probably located elsewhere.